# Unmarshaling JSON structure in go make empty maps

Tags: json, dictionary, go, unmarshalling

I have a json file, containing plenty of data:

```
{"elec":{
    "s20":{
        "coldS":{
            "wDay": {
                "Night":   {"avg": 1234, "stddev": 56},
                "Morning": {"avg": 5432, "stddev": 10}
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

I want to load this file as a go structure:

```
type ConsumConfig struct {
    elec map[string]map[string]map[string]map[string]ConsumConfValue `json:"elec"`
    gas  map[string]map[string]map[string]map[string]ConsumConfValue `json:"gas"`
}

type ConsumConfValue struct {
    avg   int `json:"avg"`
    stdev int `json:"stddev"`
}
```

When I do unmarshaling file data, I obtain an zero-value object of my struct type instead of an object full of data (obtaining `elec` = `map[]` and `gas` = `map[]`). So when I access to the value of theses map, I obtain zero-values (so `0` cause there are integers).

There is no compilation nor execution errors. I try to find if there was a problem of filename or if my file containing zeros, but it's not; there is the file (that is successfully loaded as a byte array), containing values different than 0.

Here is my code to unmarshal the file:

```
func GetConsumConfig(climatFilePath string) ConsumConfig {
    fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(climatFilePath) // get file as byte array
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var configConsum ConsumConfig
    err = json.Unmarshal(fileBytes, &configConsum) // byte array as struct
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return configConsum
}
```

And here is the test I do to view that there is anything inside the returned object:

```
fmt.Println("0...", climatFilePath)
for a, b := range returnedConfigConsum.elec {
    fmt.Println(a, ": ", b)
}
fmt.Println("1...")
for a, b := range returnedConfigConsum.gas {
    fmt.Println(a, ": ", b)
}
fmt.Println("2...")
```

And this is printing just that:

```
0... file/path.json
1...
2...
```

Instead of something like

```
0... file/path.json
s20: map[..]
s50: map[..]
s75: map[..]
1...
s20: map[..]
s50: map[..]
s75: map[..]
2...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `elec` and `gas` fields are lowercase. `json.Unmarshal` will only touch the fields starting with an uppercase. Renaming them to `Elec` and `Gas` should probably fix the issue.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand why the -1 on my question x) I'm not accustomed to that lower/uppercase changes how programs works...Thank you (I think I will delete this question soon...); Note that I have also to change `avg` and `stdev` to `Avg` and `Stdev` too (hard thing to doesn't works because of a lowercase)